# Add details to PayPal Checkout Purchase (Like Title)

Tags: javascript, paypal

I currently have a digital store on my site which is powered by PayPal. I am attempting to add a title to my purchase so the client knows what was purchased when looking at a transaction history. I've tried to find out how on the [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-item) documentation but I don't quite understand what is written nor how to implement it.

```js
function paypal_render(price, tier) {
    paypal.Buttons({
        style : {
            color: 'blue',

        },
        createOrder: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units : [{
                    amount: {
                        currency_code: 'USD',
                        value: ''+price
                    },
                }],
                application_context: {
                    shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING",
                },
                item: {
                    title: "PEANUTS LAB - TIER " + tier + "DONATION",
                }
            });
        },
        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
                console.log(details)
            })
        }
    }).render('#paypal');
}
```

Here is what the Sandbox order looks like with the current script:
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You linked to the definition of an item object, but what you need to provide is an *array* of item objects with the key `items`, as detailed for the purchase_unit object.

The root API schema for a v2/checkout/orders create is [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body)

Here is a complete example with one item and including the required amount breakdown.

```
{
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "500",
        "breakdown": {
          "item_total": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "500"
          }
        }
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Name of Item #1 (can be viewed in the upper-right dropdown during payment approval)",
          "description": "Optional description; item details will also be in the completed paypal.com transaction view",
          "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "500"
          },
          "quantity": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any fields that don't correspond to the API schema will be ignored, as in your question's example

Comment: quick reply! This is working. I had assumed I would need to put items after purchase_units, for some reason, but this is a lot more logical. Thanks!